# verify string with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have question that seems simple to you all but can't really get it. encounter warning till now.

May I know how can i accept a string with integers 0-9 and alpha a-zA-Z but minimum 5 characters and maximum 15 characters with `preg_match`.  Thanks

Comment: Why not show what you have, and what warning(s) you get?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with missing [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters).

Comment: Not specific to PHP5, please tag correctly. http://php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,15}$/D', $str)
```

Here `^` marks the begin and `$` the end of the string (the *D* modifier is to let `$` match only the end of the line without an ending line break). That means the whole string must be matched by the pattern `[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,15}` that describes a sequence of 5 to 15 characters of the character class `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: @gumbo can i use [:alnum:] instead of a-z0-9?

Comment: @benmsia: Yes, you can use `[:alnum:]` (see http://php.net/regexp.reference.character-classes).

Comment: @gumbo (regarding [:alnum:]) I'd guess rather **not**. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php

Answer (score 1):

You said in your posting

> how can i accept a string with integers 0-9 **AND** alpha a-zA-Z but

If that AND is a locigal and reads "letters && numbers", this gets more complicated:

```
 ...

 $nd = preg_match_all('/\d/', $text, $m);        # count numbers
 $na = preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]/', $text, $m);  # count characters
 $nn = $na + $nd;                                # must be like strlen($text)

 if($nn==strlen($text) && $nn>=5 && $nn<=15 && $na && $nd)
    echo "$text ok";
  else
    echo "$text not ok";

 ...
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: @benmisa, this is for a completely different use case, like in password generation if you have to have numbers and letters, but at least a number AND at least a letter: AABBB wrong, 12222 wrong, AABB1 correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, I've tested it as a spam filter on my site.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{5,80}$/D", "$name")) 
{
die("Error Occured : Please Enter Your Name Before Attempting to Send Message");
}
```